# Has any language become greatly popular for something other than its intended purpose?

Tags: programming-languages, history

Take this scenario:

- A programmer creates a language to solve some problem.
- He then releases this language to help others solve problems like it.
- Another programmer discovers it's actually much better for some different category of problems.
- By virtue of this new application, the language then becomes popular for that application primarily.

**Are there any instances of this actually occurring?**

Put another way, does the intended purpose of a language have any bearing on how it's actually used, or whether it becomes popular? Is it even important that a language *have* an advertised purpose?

Comment: Your HTML example doesn't really seem to fit with what you are looking for, are technical documents so different than any other document? HTML's core purpose is still the same as it was in 1989, to provide easy means for documents to reference each other. IMHO HTML is the exact opposite of what you are actually looking for.

Comment: Considering the long list of answers; maybe the opposite question is more interesting: what (popular) language is *just* used for it's intended purpose?

Comment: @Yannis: Good point. It's not the best example, and could really be argued either way. Edited to remove.

Comment: @Jaap: I thought the  same!

Comment: I could be wrong in this but I'm pretty sure most languages aren't used for what their creators intended.  I think the large reason for this is that outsiders don't know what it's supposed to be used for which helps them to be more open-minded about the potential a language has.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

[Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29#History). McCarthy originally specified Lisp in a paper to show that few simple notations are enough to build a turing complete language. He was surprised to find that Lisp could be implemented in machine code (Steve Russel did the first Lisp interpreter implementation). Lisp is widely used for AI programming.

Comment: +1, Lisp *was not intended to be* a programming language! I don't think you can top that.

Comment: OTOH, one could argue that LISP was designed for use at the border between programming and math, and it remains there.

Comment: I believe McCarthy used Lisp as an example in his classes and intended to write a compiler for it, but mentioned in class one day that hand-coding the eval function would implement an interpreter but of course 'no one would actually want to do that'

Comment: My Lisper friends tell me it's not used in AI so much any more, but it still has application *everywhere*.

Answer (score 111):

Java was originally intended for embedded systems programming. From Wikipedia ["Java was originally designed for interactive television"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29#History). But it became hugely popular for Application and Web programming.

Comment: Huh. Can't believe I didn't think of this one. It's arguably the canonical example...though that's not to say I won't yet be surprised.

Comment: Although, was Java ever actually released for embedded work (before embedded java, which came rather after its promotion for the web)?

Comment: The crucial design element in the design Java was the ability to run untrusted code.

Comment: the story is even worse: A) it was intended for embedded systems. B)but never saw the light until it could be embedded in webpages. C) it didn't get any respect until used for 'enterprisey' web applications and D) it finally got embedded in many phone OSs; but not as a hardware controller, it's a GUI platform instead.

Comment: There has been a project to get it onto set-top boxes for more than 10 years now--look up OCAP or tru-2way

Comment: Yeah, I think java at some stages in it's life easily answers the question. Lisp also has its points as an answer as well.

Answer (score 32):

Larry Wall's original intention for **perl** was for a "[general-purpose Unix scripting language to make report processing easier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)" and the [man page](http://luv.asn.au/overheads/perl/man.html) describes the language as:

> Perl is a interpreted language optimized for scanning  arbitrary  text  files,  extracting  information from those textfiles, and printing reports based on that information.

And of course the man page also tells us that Perl stands for *Practical Extraction and Report Language* (the actual name is a misspelling of the original name *Pearl*, changed when Wall discovered an already existing [PEARL language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEARL_(programming_language))).

Perl went a long way since then, as it is the [language from which the gods wrought the universe](http://xkcd.com/224/).

[image]

Comment: One should correct that: *Pathologically Eclectic Rubbish Lister*

Comment: There is more than one way to unabbrev! Very Perly

Comment: Any acronym for Perl is actually a backronym.

Comment: @CanSpice You're right, I'm updating the answer...

Comment: I don't get the comic.... why is the comic supposed to be witty??

Comment: @DarkTemplar The way I interpret it is that perl has crept it's way almost everywhere. From it's humble beginnings perl grew to be a very popular web language, an extremely popular scripting language, a somewhat popular multi purpose language, its regular expression syntax become something of a definitive, gave birth to another language (php) etc. Plus the comic also references lisp, which is the accepted answer to the question, so I thought it was a fun (albeit inaccurate) depiction of the relation of the two languages (one is the dreamy one, the other the one people actually use).

Comment: Hmmm... Is Perl still as popular of a language as it used to be?

Comment: @DarkTemplar Yeap. It's in the [top ten in the TIOBE index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html). Of course you souldn't take TIOBE index very seriously, it's quite relative and subjective. But still a good indication of language popularity.

Answer (score 32):

Lua was designed primarily as configuration language, and ended up finding a niche as the most popular scripting language for games (because it's small, fast, powerful, portable, easily extended and embedded, with user friendly syntax). The most popular game to use it, World of Warcraft, doesn't even really use it for configuration, using XML instead.

Comment: ...and now with LuaJIT it's finding more and more use in real-time processing applications

Comment: Not really http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29

Comment: @lukas: "Not really" *what*? Note that it's predecessors, SOL and DEL, didn't even have control flow, they were purely configuration languages. Lua was the extension of those configuration languages to include programming support.

Comment: "Lua was designed primarily as configuration language" I would say as a programming language.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "intended purpose" rather than "designed primarily as". The *intended purpose* was to use Lua where SOL and DEL were being used. These were configuration languages that users were starting to demand programming features in. Lua was created to fill that need. As the authors themselves [have stated](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/doc/hopl.pdf), "The wide adoption of Lua in games came as a surprise to us. We did not have game development as a target for Lua." That's pretty much exactly what the OP was looking for, no?

Comment: Just because Lua was originally written to replace configuration languages doesn't mean it was designed primarily as a configuration language.

Comment: @Stuart P. Bentley: See above.

Comment: What do most games use it for though? configuration?

Comment: @jk: Most games use it for scripting. For instance, World of Warcraft's entire UI is written in Lua, and there are tens of thousands of user-written addons for the game written in Lua (some of which games themselves, such as PopCap's [Peggle](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info13195-PeggleAdd-onforWoW.html). Saints Row uses it for scripting game missions. In Grim Fandango, [Lua was used to write a much of the game](http://www.grimfandango.net/?page=articles&pagenumber=2). And of course, some games (like Angry Birds) use Lua only for configuration.

Answer (score 28):

I would guess that **JavaScript** fits into this question as well because I don't think that Brendan Eich, back in the Netscape days, ever imagined that future versions of his *LiveScript* would be used to create today's so called web "applications".

JavaScript has moved from simple form validations and image rollovers to a **powerful** tool that's able to rival offline applications, both in terms of functionality and beauty.

Unfortunately though, I think many still see regard it as a toy.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it is moving towards being the assembly language of the web.  In other words, what other languages are compiled down to and executed in.  I don't believe Brendan Eich expected _that_.

Comment: have something to add: It is not just a client-side scripting language. Many projects like node.js or rhino use javascript as a server-side language

Comment: Just curious, but what is a "client-side scripting language" vs. "server-side language".......?

Comment: @DarkTemplar. A server-side scripting language is run on the server and its output is sent to the browser. A client-side scripting language is sent to the browser as-is, and run there. (Of course, the server-side language can be used to output the client-side language, if you want.) The only language which runs in most browsers is javascript.

Answer (score 19):

Erlang. It was invented a long long time ago in Ericsson labs to develop telephony applications, probably for their lines of switching and access devices. Now it has evolved into a promising general purpose dynamic language with an interesting concept of concurrency.

It would be interesting if in the future there would be more languages from the telco world crossing their lines to IT world and evolve from there, esp languages those initially designed for modeling and verification of protocols.

Comment: And wasn't it one of the inspirations for node.js?

Comment: Don't think this qualifies.  The reason Erlang was invented for telephony is they needed a general dynamic concurrency language.  It still is that.

Answer (score 15):

Pascal. Created to teach programming.

Comment: Heh, that explains a lot…

Comment: @poke: Of _curse_, I know.

Comment: Hehe, I see what you did there.

Comment: Hey, can someone please explain this answer? Lol. I'm a noob!

Comment: @Dark Templar: http://www.taoyue.com/tutorials/pascal/history.html

Answer (score 14):

**PHP** originally meant *Personal Home Page*, but today is used for a few slightly bigger web applications as well.

Comment: of course, the biggest PHP user, Facebook, is in many ways still in the personal home page market.

Comment: "PHP/FI was created by Rasmus Lerdorf in 1995, initially as a simple set of Perl scripts for tracking accesses to his online resume." It's come a long way, baby.

Comment: Whilst PHP is still very much a Web language, it's undergone a bit of a role reversal: PHP was meant to be embedded as small snippets inside HTML, whereas many projects now generate HTML strings within PHP. They still need a `<?php` tag at the start of the file though!

Answer (score 14):

I'm quite sure that **VBScript** wasn't meant for writing malware, even though that is an extremely common use for it.

Comment: Thats a bit harsh don't you think. Java and C have had their fair share of malware.

Comment: @JChild: Several years have passed since your comment. Even then, however, defending VB was a very strange thing to do.

Comment: @Magus It's not even VB. It's VBScript. You know, the files with .vbs extensions. The ones that you automatically assume are viruses when you see them.

Answer (score 13):

Initially designed as a method of making code more generic, **Template Meta Programming** in C++ was found out to be turing complete, and to this day is used to greatly improve the C++ language through libraries like boost.

Comment: ... and to bring C++ programmers to tears with excessively long build times ;-)

Comment: and horrific error messages.

Answer (score 11):

BASIC is another famous case. It's name (**Beginner's** All-purpose Symbolic Instruction Code) hints at its origin as a learners language, but it's grown quite a bit since.

Comment: heh - microsoft replaced "beginner's" with "business" and suckered in millions

Answer (score 11):

*VHDL* and *Verilog* (a.k.a. VerilogHDL) were originally intended to *describe* digital circuits and components. They were used as a form of documentation and to simulate the behavior of the components. Later, Synopsys and others developed technology that could translate (a subset of) these descriptions into a net lists of gates, which can in turn be used to produce real hardware.

VHDL and Verilog are called Hardware Description Languages (HDLs) for historical reasons. Today they are actually used as hardware *design* languages (same acronym).

Comment: Nice, real-life model driven development

Comment: @Mark Yes, VHDL is very-high-speed integrated circuit, hardware description language. Verilog is a completely different language. Verilog is sometimes also called Verilog HDL. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog

Comment: QHDL is very similar to VHDL and is used for describing circuits for quantum computers. I can't imagine a language departing quite so far from its origins.

Comment: @Mark Wow, that's interesting "QHDL"! Google shows a lot of noice. Do you have a reference?

Comment: I found out about it at Paul Blacks excellent "Quantum Computing for Programmers" session at the ACCU 2011 conference. His slides are at http://accu.org/content/conf2011/Paul-Black-QuantumComputingForProgrammers.ppt

Answer (score 10):

ML started as a language for developing and scripting a theorem prover. It was the theorem prover's "meta language".

Comment: Alright. It's worth noting that the reason this is a valid answer is that its primary application is now compilers and other such language tools (at least as far as I know).

Comment: +1, but saying that ML became "greatly popular" is a bit of a stretch

Comment: Perhaps, but in addition to its direct users today, it influenced just about every single typed language that came after it.

Answer (score 7):

**[C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29)** 
 Originally it was originally developed for use with the Unix operating system. But the Language became so popular even Dennis Ritchie was surprised.
 In his famous book [The C programming language](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=HHhGAAAAYAAJ&q=c%20the%20programming%20language&dq=c%20the%20programming%20language&hl=en&ei=rDrjTea4JcOqrAeWzNWpBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAA). Ritchie states "it has spread far beyond its origins as the language of the UNIX operating
system." and how surprised he was as it became popular language for application development.

Comment: Well, it was originally designed to develop systems and low-level applications in a cross-platform fashion. It remains consonant with its original goals despite its popularity, so it doesn't fit.

Comment: @Jon Well it kind of fits, as it outgrew it's purpose by becoming the easiest way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @Yannis: Haha, true. But I'm asking about languages whose primary purpose changed utterly, not those which simply grew to encompass more purposes.

Comment: I would add that C became popular as one of the prime languages for obfuscated code contests.

Comment: Wasn't it designed to implement the operating system?

Comment: @JonPurdy: I think "cross-platform" has changed meaning; the idea wasn't so much that one could write programs that would run usably on different platforms, but rather to allow a means of providing multiple programs with compilable languages.

Answer (score 3):

**C++** was originally designed as “C with classes” to facilitate object-oriented programming in C++.

Templates were then provided in a later version to enable the implementation of strongly-typed container classes. It was only noticed later that these templates actually constitute a Turing-complete compile-time programming language.

As a consequence, many applications now use C++ not as an object-oriented programming language but rather as a *algorithms-driven* programming language that relies heavily on compile-time polymorphism and metaprogramming.

Comment: But the C++ is designed to be general purpose, and is used as a general purpose language.

Comment: @Ubiquité I don’t think C++ really was designed as a general purpose language. Or rather, it was designed to be used *for* different purposes (but in particular systems programming). But it was *not* designed to work with multiple *paradigms*.

Comment: Actually, the multi-paradigm nature is inherent in its design, simply by virtue of bolting OO features onto C while retaining the ability to use its more procedural features where appropriate.

Comment: @Jon OK, I’ll concede that. However, generic programming and template metaprogramming weren’t among these features. And nowadays C++ is one of the only (and arguably the main) language that supports these features.

Comment: Very true. Hell, support for generic programming and `const` are *the* two most important reasons I use C++.

Answer (score 2):

**ADA** — originally designed under DoD contract for avionics. Although still used in that application, it's also popular for example for real-time business middle-ware.

Comment: It was build as a general purpose language. The DoD wanted a language usable for everything, to reduce the amount of different language used.

Comment: That's pretty hilarious. Ada was a language explicitly created with the goal of reducing the number of different languages out there. By that metric ("designed with one purpose, used for another") Ada should be voted up to the top of the list with Lisp, another anti-language language.

Answer (score 2):

"does the intended purpose of a language have any bearing on how it's actually used, or whether it becomes popular?"

I don't think the intended purpose of a language has much bearing on its actual use and popularity: There are some great languages that were designed from the start to be innovative, flexible and versitile, but never became that widely used or popular except in very specialized vertical markets - for example Eiffel. OTOH, Basic, Pascal, C etc etc dominated the landscape for years although they were designed originally for limited, specific purposes.

IMO Marketing/financial and **support**  considerations have always played a major role in the spread and extension of certain languages. For example: Borland comes up with TurboPascal and packages, markets and supports it. MS comes up with C# and packages, markets and supports it. As a result, these languages became popular, third party tool industries sprung up and more and more developers and enterprises jump on the bandwagon.

But for the last few years, openSource languages and tools are changing the dynamic and languages now become popular based more on 'merit' than marketing - for example Ruby, Python and Perl. But that's not because of the 'intent' of the inventors so much as the language's built in potential for extension and expedient usage.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a popular language that has not been repurposed from it's original intent.  Even C was originally written to make a portable OS (unix).

Any attempt to write a truly generic programming language with no specific target in mind would probably fail miserably due to a lack of restraint and focus.

Comment: postscript - is ubiquitous (in almost every computer and printer), but only used for printing graphics.  Although, one could argue that it was repurposed when used within pdf's.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard [Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/chapter-2.html#section1) was designed as a language to write poetry in, turned out you can write pretty beautiful code in it as well!

> I’ll be straight with you. I want you to cry. To weep. To whimper sweetly. This book is a poignant guide to Ruby. That means code so beautiful that tears are shed. That means gallant tales and somber truths that have you waking up the next morning in the arms of this book.

Comment: Sounds... interesting. Any source?

Comment: The Ruby link takes you to a book that was written to teach Ruby in an artistic way. My answer is a joke in reference to that book which asserts writing Ruby is like poetry. In reality one might say that Ruby was designed to be a general purpose programming language but it inspired (some) people to look at Ruby code as poetry.